# Mapping concrete emotions to the PAD model

Tags: emotion, model

I'm in the middle of researching emotional models.

I've come across the PANA model and there are nice mappings out there of emotional words to various points on the PANA plane—the ["Mood Meter"](https://www.ps120q.org/mood-meter/), for instance.

Are there any similar mappings of emotional words to the 3-dimensional PAD model?

Comment: The best I've found so far comes from http://www.kaaj.com/psych/scales/emotion.html, but no sources are cited for this data:  The following sample ratings illustrate definitions of various emotion terms when scores on each PAD scale range from -1 to +1: angry (-.51, .59, .25), bored (-.65, -.62, -.33), curious (.22, .62, -.01), dignified (.55, .22, .61), elated (.50, .42, .23), hungry (-.44, .14, -.21), inhibited (-.54, -.04, -.41), loved (.87, .54, -.18), puzzled (-.41, .48, -.33), sleepy (.20, -.70, -.44), unconcerned (-.13, -.41, .08), violent (-.50, .62, .38)

Comment: I've also found this: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-distribution-of-9-emotional-states-words-in-PAD-emotion-space-The-center-of-each_fig1_226488121